# Firefox Bookmarklet drag 'n' drop has no title

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, bookmarklet

we created a Bookmarklet in our Web Application, that can be added to the browser's bookmarks bar via drag and drop. The code looks basically like the following:

```
<a 
    href="javascript:(function() { var x = .... })();"
    onclick=" alert('Drag and Drop this link to your browser\'s bookmark bar');return false; "
    class="btn btn-primary">The Bookmarklet
</a>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and if you drag the button link to your bookmarks bar you can read "The Bookmarklet" as title, while in Firefox (v. 47.0.1) the title field remains empty and you only get the default favicon without text.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Different browsers do things differently... There's no bookmarklet specification that would dictate how to set a default name for the bookmark as far as I'm aware...

Comment: I created [a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/fasocecapu/1/edit?html,output). It works fine for me on Firefox/50.1 (Win64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured out thet was because of the styling properties. When I removed the btn class from the bookmarklet everythin worked well.